# RCP plugin obfuscation with proguard

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, proguard, rcp

I'm working on plugin obfuscation. In general, obfuscation is working (at target I have obfuscated jar), but when I'm building product, there is no obfuscated plugin. When I add some methods to the code, method is in product. I have no idea why not obfuscated plugin is at product. I'm using `maven-tycho`, `p2` and jenkins as builder. Here is my maven configuration for obfuscation with maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <proguardVersion>5.2</proguardVersion>
        <options>
            <option>-keep class org.apache.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class org.osgi.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class org.eclipse.** { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep class * extends
                org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin
            </option>
            <option>-keep class * extends org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart</option>
            <option>-keep class * implements org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard</option>
            <option>-keep class * implements
                org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPlatformRunnable
            </option>
            <option>-dontshrink</option>
            <option>-dontoptimize</option>
            <option>-dontpreverify</option>
            <option>-obfuscationdictionary keywords</option>
            <option>-classobfuscationdictionary keywords</option>
            <option>-keeppackagenames **view**</option>
        </options>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe will be useful for somebody, I changed from `<phase>install</phase>` to package, and right now everything is working fine. It looklike this that with tycho jar is putting into p2 repository before install maven phase.